# Github Desktop / VsCcode Authentication failed

Tags: git, github, ssh, connection

I've some issues trying to use git with another app than git bash.
(I'm on Windows)

With git desktop I have an Authentication failed error :

> Authentication failed. Some common reasons include:
>
> - You are not logged in to your account: see File > Options.
> - You may need to log out and log back in to refresh your token.
> - You do not have permission to access this repository.
> - The repository is archived on GitHub. Check the repository settings to confirm you are still permitted to push commits.
> - If you use SSH authentication, check that your key is added to the ssh-agent and associated with your account.

With VsCode I have

```
Git : git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

and this error log :

```sh
git pull --tags origin main
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse main
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{u}
git rev-list --left-right main...refs/remotes/origin/main
git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
git remote --verbose
git config --get commit.template
```

I've tried to disconect/reconnenct from git desktop, change my `~/.profile`, create an ssh agent, restart my computer.... But nothing work

I've check and I've the same key witch `ssh-add -l` and in github

Here you can see screens of command I try and didn't execute as expected:

[image: shell]

Comment: I also have an error when I do
```$ ssh -v git@github.com```
I have an error message and a success message I don't know if there are a link beetwen that and the authentification error

- PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

- Hi Phorcys-1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

- Connection to github.com closed.

Answer (score 0):

If `ssh -Tv git@github.com` does work in a git (For Windows) bash shell session, that means you must have (do check) a public/private key pair in %USERPROFILE%

Open a CMD (not a git bash), `cd %USERPROFILE%\.ssh` and look for a `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub` file.
If the private key was created without passphrase, you don't need `ssh-add -l`: that is only for passphrase-protected private keys.

If you don't see them, look at the output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com` in order to see where are the key actually used by openssh.

Check also in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` for a config file, which might in it the right path for those keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've well have the keys in my ~/.ssh and my private key was created with a passphrase.
Ans this is how look my config file : 

Host git@github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 User Phorcys-1
 AddKeysToAgent yes

Comment: @Julio OK: try for testing to recreate your keys without passphrase, register your public key to GitHub and rename your config file (you don't need it in that case)

Comment: @Julio For a personal use, that is what I would recommend.

Comment: Yes but it's for a teamWork... I'll won't keep a key without passphrase a long time

Comment: @Julio Then try again with your key passphrase-protected, but don't use a config file

Comment: @Julio Use instead https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com`

OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

- debug1: Reading configuration data C:\Users\soari/.ssh/config
- debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
- debug1: Connection established.
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
- debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
- debug1: identity file C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
- debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
- debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-c863b32e
- debug1: no match: babeld-c863b32e
- debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
- debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
- debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
- debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
- debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
- debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
- debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
- debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
- debug1: Found key in C:\Users\soari/.ssh/known_hosts:5
- debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
- debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
- debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
- debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
- debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
- debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
- debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:UgTMuv+9mt7CPvBKvP5LY0C7ArLvmV1eHd+9q83x/6U C:\Users\soari/.ssh/id_rsa
- debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 407
  warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
- debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.4]:22).
- debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
- debug1: Entering interactive session.
- debug1: pledge: network
  Hi Phorcys-1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
- debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
- debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
  Transferred: sent 2944, received 2596 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
  1